# What did Pascal mean: 'A vapour, a drop of water, suffices to kill him'?

Tags: pascal

<sub>Source: p 29 (Top), [*Introducing Philosophy for Canadians: A Text with Integrated Readings*](https://www.amazon.ca/Introducing-Philosophy-Canadians-Integrated-Readings/dp/0195430964) (2011 1 ed).

[Primary Source:](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/roseau_pensant)   Fragment 347, [*Pensées*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es) by Blaise Pascal</sub>

> L’homme n’est qu’un roseau, le plus faible de la nature; mais c’est un roseau pensant. Il ne faut pas que l’univers entier s’arme pour l’écraser : **une vapeur, une goutte d’eau, suffit pour le tuer**. Mais, quand l’univers l’écraserait, l’homme serait encore plus noble que ce qui le tue, parce qu’il sait qu’il meurt, et l’avantage que l’univers a sur lui, l’univers n’en sait rien.

Is the bolded allegorical, and not literal?

My conjecture: Was Pascal referring to [water conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_conflict)?

Comment: You can find on the web many [comments](http://degaulle.lyc.ac-amiens.fr/matieres/philosophie/guyon/corriges/pascalrosopensant.htm) on this (and many other) *Penseées*: it is a typocal *lycee* homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to paraphrase (not literally translate) what the quote says:

First sentence: Thesis.

> Man isn't as fragile as rose, a self-sufficient being, but even more, so that he can be brought out of his equilibrium by such simple phenomena as vapour or a drop of water, because he has to *think* about it.

Second sentence: Explication.

> He (identified with his thinking!) *has to evolve*, include every single phenomenon into the framework of his thinking, and therefore his self-conception is always endangered by the universe (read: nature/phenomena) to be challenged and eventually "crushed". Man then has to reinvent himself, the old self is killed, and a new, more noble one, is born. But in the end, it is man how "kills" himself, not nature.

The [link out of the comment](http://degaulle.lyc.ac-amiens.fr/matieres/philosophie/guyon/corriges/pascalrosopensant.htm) of @MauroAllegranza pretty much contextualises this historically as I understand (only six years french in school, maybe I got all wrong ;).

Therefore, the **violability allegorically expressed** in the first sentence is nothing more than the other side of the medal of "Toute notre dignité consiste donc en la pensée." - All our dignity consists therefore in the thinking. - The sentence following your quote within the very same Pensée, leading to a notion of morals. It is our source of nobility to cope with the universe in thinking, always throwing over our obsolete self-understanding.

Comment: I don't really agree with your paraphrase of Pascal's text. It seems to me that you got confused with the French sentences and changed th emeaning quite a bit.